Brown patches on pothos plant
Recently I got this pothos plant. Initially it was good, but after a few days, the leaves started having small brown patches as well as some small holes on leaves. I have kept it in my room at a temperature of around 22° C, in shade (without sunlight).
Can you tell me the issue with it, is it watering or the AC or something else?



If a houseplant starts to show signs like yours only a few days after purchase, the problem or cause is down to the store you bought it from and often it is a result of packing and shipping issues from the grower to the store or bad handling in the store.
We shall never know, but it is nothing you have done wrong - plants are far more slow to react to changed circumstances or micro-environments than us humans and you must be prepared to accept some transit damage along the way. That damage could have occurred a month ago for all we know.
So, just take it as normal for houseplants and providing the growing tips are not brown and dying, expect some blemishes along the way.
Remember that a pothos is an epiphytic climber in the wild, climbing up trees and crawling its way across the forest floor. They are sturdy plants and can take a lot of rough handling before they die. To be frank, they are pretty much impossible to kill.
So, my advice is to do nothing, just ensure it gets enough light, don't leave it standing in water and keep it away from draughts and high heat or cold sources.
And don't forget to keep taking cuttings to ensure the plant does not get leggy. A moss pole is a great surface for the plant to grow into and often you can take cuttings from within the pole and you do not need to put them in water first.
That said, my healthiest and biggest pothos plants are growing 100% of the time in my aquarium, all that fish poop gives it great fertiliser. So if you fancy growing cuttings or full plants hydroponically, you can do that too.
In the meantime, don't worry and enjoy your plant and do not snip away any damaged leaves unless you have OCD - the plant will take back up any nutrients from a damaged plant and ultimately leave you with a brown crumbly leaf that will fall off its own accord.
